# Not able to import "@angular/material" module

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-material, mean-stack

I'm totally new to mean stack and I'm facing some problems with Angular's material module. I'm trying to import the "@angular/material" module in my code but I'm getting an error whenever I'm importing it. The error is as follows:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:5:32 - error TS2306: File '/Users/anmolsarraf/Desktop/MEAN Stack/mean-course/node_modules/@angular/material/index
.d.ts' is not a module.
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
   {
  "name": "mean-course",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animation": "^4.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/material": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.7",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PostCreateComponent } from './posts/post-create/post-create.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostCreateComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

To be exact I'm trying to do `import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';` and I'm getting the above-mentioned error.

I have tried importing the above module as `import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';` but then it throws a bunch of error saying `node_modules/@angular/material/input/input.d.ts:138:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.`

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I created a new instance of an Angular app and then tried to import angular material in it, somehow it worked since I'm not getting any errors while importing it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `npm install` after adding it to your project?

Comment: Yeah, I executed that command as well after adding it to my project, but no success :-(

Comment: Post your import statement as well

Comment: I have added the import statements above in the question.

Comment: It might be due to `@angular/material` being v9 and Angular v8, but not entirely sure. Can you make sure the versions of Angular and Angular Material are the same? (remove node_modules, reinstall etc)

Comment: Tried removing the node_modules and reinstalling it, but still no success with it.

Answer (score 15):

> Create one new module.ts file. for example, you can create
>   material.module.ts and prepare all the material libraries in it like
>   below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { A11yModule } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { ClipboardModule } from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { CdkStepperModule } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { CdkTreeModule } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatBottomSheetModule } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    A11yModule,
    ClipboardModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule
  ],
  imports: [
    A11yModule,
    ClipboardModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

> import this model in the app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent        
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,       
    MaterialModule    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Nice! Added the line to the imports:

import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

Comment: The problem is that vscode doesn't import when the folder is two or more deep. here is the thread that explains that. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31763

Answer (score 10):

You need to be more specific:

```
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
```

not just

```
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';
```

and then 
add it to your imports

Comment: I tried that approach as well but no success. I have mentioned this approach above in my question, please refer to the question for more details.

Comment: try restarting angular.

Comment: unfortunately, no luck !

Answer (score 6):

I had also faced the same issue when I started using Angular Material for the first time and didn't know the installation process.

First, you need to install angular material by command:

```
npm install --save @angular/material
```

Then add angular material in your project with this command:

```
ng add @angular/material
```

For me, it started working by these two simple commands.

Answer (score 2):

Because **Angular/material** version is higher than 8.0.0 and you should be more specific.

If you open `node_modules/@angular` folder and go to `material folder`, the components is organized into folders and to use it write component name after `material/`

Note: IF you didn't found `material folder`, you should install @angular/material package first :

> npm install --save @angular/material

And to use Input material that version is higher than 8 will be write component name after `material/` for example:

> `import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';`

If the `Angular/material` version is less than or equal 8.0.0 the import will be like the next format:

> `import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';`

Answer (score 1):

Did you run the command `ng add @angular/material?`?

You can also try going through the angular material docs here: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Also, are you taking the mean course by Maximilian Schwarzmüller? If you're not too far into it, try seeing if you missed any steps (I'm guessing because the name "mean-course" is used for his project too :)

EDIT:
In your imports module, you put the line
`import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';`
but forgot to add it to your imports array :)

change it to this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostCreateComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule //new import
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Edit 2:
if that still doesn't work, try running this command: 
`ng update --next @angular/cli --force` or updating typescript using `npm install -g typescript@latest` or `npm update`

Comment: I had a look at the documentation and I made sure to follow each every step mentioned in the documentation but unfortunately, I'm still getting the error. And yes I'm taking the mean course by Maximilian Schwarzmüller. I have reviewed the video several times to make sure I followed each and every step but unfortunately, nothing worked.

Comment: I actually have that course too, what a coincidence! I'm not sure if stack overflow gives you a notification whenever an answer gets edited but I think the issue is in your app.module.ts

Comment: Tried making the changes that you have mentioned above, but still, it's throwing me the following error: ' node_modules/@angular/material/input/input.d.ts:138:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context '

Comment: have you tried upgrading typescript? also try checking the comment section of your course, sometimes people have the same issue there and Max usually replies and helps them solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there are so many version mismatch in your package.json.

Can your try `ng update` , then you will see something like this:

```
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 80 dependencies.
We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

  Name                                Version                  Command to update
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @angular/cdk                        7.3.7 -> 10.1.3          ng update @angular/cdk
  @angular/cli                        8.3.25 -> 10.0.8         ng update @angular/cli
  @angular/core                       8.2.14 -> 10.0.14        ng update @angular/core
  @ngrx/store                         7.4.0 -> 10.0.0          ng update @ngrx/store
  rxjs                                6.5.4 -> 6.6.2           ng update rxjs
```

Then please update the required dependencies

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you imported material using `ng add @angular/material`, then just right click on your project, reload from disk and error will go away..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the OP. I could not pin point the cause but I believe it may have been an issue with the package manager adding conflicting versions of the Material package. I recently switched to using PNPM over NPM. I first started to see this issue after running `pnpm install @angular/material`. The package installed successfully but I had the errors the OP had above whenever I ran the server, `ng serve`. 
Like the OP I tried all the suggestions but none worked. I even tried installing the specific version of Material that worked previously `pnpm i @angular/material@8.2.3` but that didn't work either.

What worked was globally [setting PNPM as my package manager in the Anglar CLI configurations](https://medium.com/@beeman/using-yarn-with-angular-cli-v6-7f53a7678b93).

```
ng config -g cli.packageManager pnpm // Set PNPM globally
ng config cli.packageManager pnpm    // Set PNPM for single project
ng config -g cli.packageManager npm  // Set NPM globally, default
```

Afterwards, I created a new project and installed the Material package using `ng add @angular/material`. It took a while but it everything installed successfully.
In both instances PNMP was used instead of NPM.
I was also able to import the Material modules using the old syntax.

```
import {MatCardModule, MatIconModule, MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it resolved by importing the MatInputModule from '@angular/material/input'.

```
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
```